# Passar código via url com/para um java script (php+codeigniter)

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Olá, tenho o seguinte caso. Tenho um parte com apenas alguns dados de vários locais, gostaria de fazer algo para abrir um pop-up para mostrar todos os dados desse local, para isso precisaria passar o id do mesmo para a url para fazer o select. Método aonde eu estou

```
foreach ($dadosLocais as $row) {
  $marker = array();
  $marker['position'] = $row->latitude . ',' . $row->longitude;
  $marker['title'] = $row->nome_nascente;
  $dadosUsuario = $this->Usuario_model->getUsuario()->row();
  $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<h2>' . $row->nome_nascente . '</h2>' . 'Descrição: '
  . $row->descricao_nascente . '</br>' . 'Latitude: ' . $row->latitude
  . '</br>' . 'Longitude: ' . $row->longitude
  . '</br>' . 'Usuário que Cadastrou: ' . $dadosUsuario->nome
  .'</br>' . 'Imagem: ' . '<a href="javascript:abrir(500,200)"> Visualizar Imagem</a>'; }
```

Já o meu java script é:

```
    <script languague="javascript">
  function abrir(largura, altura){ window.open('<?= site_url('Nascente/verImagem') ?>','popup','width='+largura+',height='+altura+',scrolling=auto,top=0,left=0') }
</script>
```

O pop-up está abrindo corretamente, eu apenas não sei como passar o id_local que está no forearch para o java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que vá ser algo assim. Eu assumi que o `$row->ID_LOCAL` está no `$row`, veja se é isso mesmo. E eu alterei a order dos parâmetros passando primeiro o ID pra função de popup, e depois a `largura, altura`. Se preferir o contrário, basta alterar a ordem.

```
foreach ($dadosLocais as $row) {
  $marker = array();
  $marker['position'] = $row->latitude . ',' . $row->longitude;
  $marker['title'] = $row->nome_nascente;
  $dadosUsuario = $this->Usuario_model->getUsuario()->row();
  $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<h2>' . $row->nome_nascente . '</h2>' . 'Descrição: '
  . $row->descricao_nascente . '</br>' . 'Latitude: ' . $row->latitude
  . '</br>' . 'Longitude: ' . $row->longitude
  . '</br>' . 'Usuário que Cadastrou: ' . $dadosUsuario->nome
  .'</br>' . 'Imagem: ' . '<a href="javascript:abrir(' . $row->ID_LOCAL . ',500,200)"> Visualizar Imagem</a>'; 

}
```

Não conheço a função `site_url` do seu framework, talvez ela tenha opção de já passar parâmetros querystring. Se tiver, use isso e não faça essa concatenação que eu fiz abaixo:

```
<script languague="javascript">
    function abrir(idLocal, largura, altura) { 
        window.open('<?= site_url('Nascente/verImagem') ?>?idLocal=' + idLocal, 'popup', 'width='+largura+',height='+altura+',scrolling=auto,top=0,left=0');
    }
</script>
```